# How do I assign a value in an array when a mouse is pressed SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to make a program where you are allowed to select between an option of shapes, and then drawing it. To allow for multiple shapes I created a vector of a class which creates shapes (Shapes are set up with the chosen function). My problem is the mouse click is too long, so it assigns it to everything in the vector, so you can't create a new shape. Is there a problem in my logic, or is there a problem in the code?

Here is my attempt:

```
for (auto& it : onCanvas) {
        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (mousepointer.getGlobalBounds().intersects(circleOption.getGlobalBounds())) {
                it.chosen(circles);
            }
            if (mousepointer.getGlobalBounds().intersects(rectOption.getGlobalBounds())) {
                it.chosen(rectangle);
            }
            if (mousepointer.getGlobalBounds().intersects(triOption.getGlobalBounds())) {
                it.chosen(triangles);
            }
            if (mousepointer.getGlobalBounds().intersects(it.shape.getGlobalBounds()) || it.dragging) {
                it.shape.setPosition(mousepointer.getPosition());
                it.dragging = true;
            }
        }
        if (!Mouse::isButtonPressed) {
            it.dragging = false;
        }
        win.draw(it.shape);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source-code is a bit incomplete (what is `onCanvas` and `mousepointer`). But I guess the problem is that this snippet is called multiple times while your mouse is clicked. To avoid that you can do two thing.

In the first solution you use [events](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php), so you only add shapes when the state of the mousebutton changes (you can additionally listen to the `MouseButtonReleased` to simulate a full click):

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
{
    if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
    {
        // Hit Detection
    }
}
```

or second solution you remember the last state of the button (probably do the mouse check once outside of the for loop):

```
bool mouse_was_up = true;
if (mouse_was_up  && Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
    mouse_was_up = false;
    for (auto& it : onCanvas) {
        // Hit Detection
    }
}
else if (!Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
    mouse_was_up = true;
```

I would rather stick to the first solution because when your click is too short and your gameloop is in another part of the game logic, you can miss the click.

Comment: The second solution works! I dunno why the first one didn't, but it's fine since what I'm doing is fairly small. I'm still learning, so I'm just working on some beginner projects..